# when the searched product does not exist in database then how to show that searched product?

Tags: magento2, database, search, catalogsearch

In the search engine i have searched one product.that product not in the database but product is moving to add to cart page and store in the database and it will show the message **not in stock but in short time will give you the product**.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

there are a magento simple way  via admin configuration , if you enable this, you will have this product

https://bsscommerce.com/blog/how-to-enable-stock-alert-and-display-out-of-stock-product-in-magento-2/

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-displaydisable-out-of-stock-product-by-your-own/

if I right understood ...

Comment: 1)we want that still our user can able to add that searched product in the cart without price with a message "we will call you shortly for your required product."
2. and after placing order this order should show in our admin panel order section also.

Comment: create a plugin or observer for search , get query , programmatically create this product and add it to the user shopping cart

Answer (score 0):

this is easy, first search where you can get a query from search  and then just create product with this name , sku etc. and just use this :

```
protected $formKey;   
protected $cart;
protected $product;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
array $data = []) {
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->product = $product;      
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
 { 
  $productId =10;
  $params = array(
                'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                'product' => $productId, //product Id
                'qty'   =>1 //quantity of product                
            );              
    //Load the product based on productID   
    $_product = $this->product->load($productId);       
    $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
    $this->cart->save();
 }
```